# Create zip file from in memory file in python

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, zip

I am retrieving files from S3 bucket using the following code an it works fine.

```
file = io.BytesIO()
k.get_contents_to_file(file)
```

Now I want to add this in memory file to a zip file. The code below takes filename  as argument but I have an in memory file.

```
zip_file.write(filename, zip_path)
```

I am using python 3.4 for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `writestr`

> Signature: writestr(zinfo_or_arcname, data, compress_type=None)
>
> Docstring: Write a file into the archive.  The contents is 'data',
>   which may be either a 'str' or a 'bytes' instance; if it is a 'str',
>   it is encoded as UTF-8 first. 'zinfo_or_arcname' is either a ZipInfo
>   instance or the name of the file in the archive.